# how to remove extra white space

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I was working in this site [My Site](http://constantin-entertainment.info/pinterclass/) after i completed almost the work only I noticed there is a white space for no reason to th eright side of the home page.Its appearing only in the home page not in any other page. In the home page template i actually added the below code to social links to appear

```
<div class="ss"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none"></a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=175266875876185&amp;href=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=lucida+grande&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

<g:plusone size="medium" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></g:plusone></div>
```

and i have given the css as

```
.ss{margin: -12px 0 0 120px;}
```

I have only changed this css.Any one please help me to get rid of that white space.Thank you!!

Comment: You have inline width styling being applied which is presumably being applied by javascipt which would seem to indicate this is a JS issue

Comment: im not good in js .. any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the facebook social share as illustrated in my image

[image]

To solve it, add this css:

```
.ss iframe {
   width: 85px !important;
}
```

Comment: so simple .. thought have to go into js ..nice that u helped

Comment: Will `display: inline-block` works? I am asking because I couldn't able to check.

Answer (score 0):

The #box-container have inline style width: 1440px; and this cause the issue.

Comment: That value is being applied by javascipt which would seem to indicate this is a JS issue.

Comment: Actually, @Mohamed Nabil is right ... the problem come from FB iframe.